# multiple date selection on pikaday

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please Help Me.

I am using Pikady.js datepickler .I want to select multiple dates on that.

Thank You.

```js
<script src="../pikaday.js"></script>
    
    <script>

    var picker2months = new Pikaday(
    {
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        field: document.getElementById('datepicker-2months'),
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
        yearRange: [2000, 2020],
  
    });
    </script>
```

```html
 <h1 id="datepicker-2months">Pikaday</h1>
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code like html. that you tried so far

Comment: In HTML I have only the h1 tag. And pikaday.js file.

Comment: @Shubhranshu Did u got it?